# I can't get the current state value in `beforeunload` event when refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(prevCounter => prevCounter + 1)
    }, 1000)
    return () => clearInterval(intervalID)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload)
  }, [])

  const handleUnload = () => {
    console.log('INSIDE handleUnload: ', counter)
    // code to save progress to local storage....
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {counter}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When refresh the page, `handleUnload` event is called and print `INSIDE handleUnload: 0` always, though the counter value is other than 0.

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-wildflower-ey5vb?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is due to closures. When you bind your handler, it's closed over what the initial state so currently for the lifetime of your component, the value of count will always be 0 inside of the handler.

There are two ways you can do this.

You can add a ref and also track the current counter value in that so you can always get the most recent state value like

```
const counterRef = useRef()
counterRef.current = counter

// ...
const handleUnload = () => {
  // will be initial
  console.log('INSIDE handleUnload: ', counter)
  // will be current
  console.log('INSIDE handleUnload: ', counterRef.current)
}
```

Or, the simplest way, you can just reattach your event listener on state change by updating your effect to run again like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload)
  return () => window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload)
}, [counter])
```

Comment: How about in class component?

Comment: You won't really encounter the same issues in a class component because it's not just function calls and closures. As long as the functions a bound, you can do just do `this.state` and get the current state just about anywhere: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-benz-f40w2

Comment: I don't know why the handler for `beforeunload` event is called two times. One with the current value and second with 0.

Answer (score 1):

## Your counter is kind of snapshotted

When adding event listeners with state you need to add any state that is used internally to that useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload)
  }, [counter])
```

Comment: How about in a class component?

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(prevCounter => prevCounter + 1);
    }, 1000);

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleUnload);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleUnload);
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    };
  });

  const handleUnload = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("INSIDE handleUnload: ", counter);
    // code to save progress to local storage....
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox {counter}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

According to [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) on MDN

> According to the specification, to show the confirmation dialog an event handler should call `preventDefault()` on the event.

Further on [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-mirzakhani-xuguu?file=/src/App.js)